# Auotamatically provide a linebreak every time I input a new line under align*

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, line-breaking

Apologies if this has been asked before; I couldn't find any other such questions. Currently, when I use the `align*` environment from LaTeX, I have to manually `\\` for every new line. Is there a way, at most importing the `amsmath` package, to automatically do this? For example, instead of

```
\begin{align*}
2 a^2 - 2 ab &= a^2 + ab - 2 ab\\
2 (a^2 - a b) &= 1 (a^2 - a b)\\
1 &= 2
\end{align*}
```

is there some way to make the middle part the following?

```
2 a^2 - 2 ab &= a^2 + ab - 2 ab
2 (a^2 - a b) &= 1 (a^2 - a b)
1 &= 2
```

Comment: you could do this but why? it would make your source code very fragile and hard to read and probably incompatible with many packages (to do it, just use `\obelines` and define `\obeyedline` to be `\\ `)

Comment: Note that even Typst require explicit denotation of newline. Perhaps one reason is that the user might want to break long line into multiple lines. --- that said, yes if you know TeX programming you can hack something away with `obeylines` --- be careful with the last line however.

Comment: How would you deal with the case where your source code needs a line break (e.g. for readability) but the typeset equations do not?

Comment: That's easy: I don't! The usage case of this is a place where TeX is interpolated into homework to make equations. I plan to only use this in equation chains, so I wouldn't have to worry about anything else, as all the TeX is isolated and turned into SVGs. I'll try \obeylines. @DavidCarlisle would you mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: @AaronLiu no, if you get something working feel free to post a self answer.